# ajaxtoolkit accordion panel, cancel edit mode in gridview when header of panel is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ajax accordion panel with 4 panes. Each pane has a gridview in it. The gridview structure and controls IDs are the same across all 4 gridviews, allowing me to share methods for loading, saving, etc.

Because of these shared IDs, if I click edit in one gridview, switch panes, click edit in another gridview an error is thrown because of ID conflicts.

If I have gridview 1 in edit mode in Panel 1, is there a way to exit that edit mode when I click one of the other panel's headers?

Comment: You shouldn't need to rely on duplicate IDs to share access to client-side methods, so I disagree with the premise of this question. If you are able to show one of the shared methods, someone should be able to help you to change it so that it's not tied to a specific ID.

Comment: @IvanKarajas duplicate IDs are not being used to share client-side methods, duplicate Ids within the gridview (think controls in itemtemplates) are being used so that codebehind methods can be used across gridviews, thus loading, saving of gridview data